# Hidden Columns in Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I have created some parameters in Access query which I dont want to show while export but unfortunately when I uncheck the show parameter, the calculation also effects the other column because I have only want to show the result not the calculations.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Often you wish other minor adjustments too (format, rounding, etc.), so create a new simple select query with the current query as source.

Then select only you fields you wish to export, and use this second query for export.